# Зачем нужны акрессоры в объектах?

Tags: javascript

Нашел простой пример

```
var dummy = {

    name: 'empty',
    description: 'static description',

    getName: function () {
        return 'name value is: ' + this.name;
    },
    setName: function (value) {
        this.name = value;
    },
    getDesc: function () {
        return 'description value is: ' + this.description;
    }

};

dummy.setName(100)
alert(dummy.getName()) //10
```

Кто может подсказать зачем они введены? Какой практический смысл? Чем это отличается от

```
dummy.name=100;
dummy.name//100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если использовать паттерн "модуль":

```
var dummy = (function(){
    var name = 'empty',
        description = 'static description';
    return {
        getName:  function () {
            return 'name value is: ' + name;
        },
        setName: function (value) {
            name = value;
        },
        getDesc: function () {
            return 'description value is: ' + description;
        }
    }
}());
```

то это ничего не даст:

```
dummy.name=100;
dummy.name//100
```

и доступ к данным обеспечивают только аксессоры, и полность контролируют - могут не пропустить нежелательное или "опасное" значение:

```
name = value.trim().length > 0 ? value : name; // не пропускаем пустые строки в качестве name
```

или как вы заметили декорировать вывод:

```
return 'name value is: ' + name;
```

Comment: как всегда спасибо тебе.

Answer (score 2):

ООП, также есть [Google Closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler). Некоторые редакторы поддерживают эту вещь, и при обращении dummy.name, они выделяют это как warning или ошибку.